# Execute a class only if a condition is met in a try statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to execute a specific class if a condition is met. If my first condition is met in my try statement, I want to run the code below class bothnotexist and ignore the other class. If my second condition is met, I want to run the code below class usernotexist and ignore the other class.
Do you know how to handle that ?

```
class bothnotexist(Exception):
   print('the user and the service connection do not exist')
   # some actions here

class usernotexist(Exception):
   print('the user does not exist but the service connection exists')
   # some actions here

def lambda_handler(event, context):

   client = boto3.client('iam')
   client.get_user(UserName='Tom') 
   try:
      if client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException and 'Test05' not in name:
         raise bothnotexist('both do not exist, raise class bothdonotexist')
       if client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException and 'Test05' in name:
          raise usernotexist(' user does not exist, raise class usernotexist')
   except:
      print ('no action required')
```

Comment: Unfortunately `it seems it's not working` is not a description of the symptoms. Please state exactly what you mean by `execute a specific class`

Comment: You don't need `try .. except` at all, just add `else` and put your last `print()` inside. Read [8.4. Raising Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions).

Comment: If I don't use the try, I will get the error NoSuchEntity in the line "client.get_user" and my code will stop.

Comment: Your `client.get_user()` call is not inside `try .. except`, so

Answer (score 0):

You want to print the statement when you raise your custom exception?

I think overriding the `__init__()` method will work.

```
class bothnotexist(Exception):
    def __init__(self, text, *args):
        print('the user and the service connection do not exist')
        super().__init__(*args):
```

Answer (score 0):

The print stament is not necessary.

You can do just this:

```
class bothnotexist(Exception):
    pass

class usernotexist(Exception):
    pass

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   client = boto3.client('iam')
   client.get_user(UserName='Tom') 
   try:
      if client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException and 'Test05' not in name:
         raise bothnotexist('both do not exist, raise class bothdonotexist')
       if client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException and 'Test05' in name:
          raise usernotexist(' user does not exist, raise class usernotexist')
   except:
      print ('no action required')
```

Or if you want to hardcode the message, you can do:

```
class bothnotexist(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('the user and the service connection do not exist')


class usernotexist(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('the user does not exist but the service connection exists')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   client = boto3.client('iam')
   client.get_user(UserName='Tom') 
   try:
      if client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException and 'Test05' not in name:
         raise bothnotexist()
       if client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException and 'Test05' in name:
          raise usernotexist()
   except:
      print ('no action required')
```

Comment: Do you understand that in case if any of conditions passed you will get also `no action required` message in console? Could you explain why do you use `try .. except` in code?

Comment: @OlvinRoght is the original code of the question, I only modified the behaviour of the exceptions, to achieve the result Liyas asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `try: except` incorrectly.

You need to put the call to `get_user` inside in the `try:` block, and specify the exception type you're handling in the `except`:

```
try:
    client.get_user(UserName='Tom')
except client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException:
    if 'Test05' in name:
        raise usernotexist(' user does not exist, raise class usernotexist')
    else:
        raise bothnotexist('both do not exist, raise class bothdonotexist')
else:
    print ('no action required')
```